# Excel VBA – Update Column BF cell based on input into Column D

Tags: excel, vba, auto-update

Hello and thank you for your time in advance.

I'm using Excel 360 (64bit)

My VBA skills are very amateurish, so I have been unable to resolve this myself by pasting and adapting code.

I’m not sure if the code should go into a Module or the worksheet object.

I have a ‘log sheet’ where a user enters the date and various other details into a number of columns.

What I would like is, each time a user enters the date in Column D, VBA executes a formula automatically as a value in Column BF. If a cell in Column D is blank, then the cell in column BF should be blank until the user enters the date.

I would also like the formula =IF(D2="","","SRC" & YEAR(TODAY()) & TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()),"00") & "-" & TEXT(ROW()-1,"0000")) to be in VBA rather than in the cells of Column BF as it slows down the workbook. (refer to sample sheet)

[image: Sample of Worksheet]

The formula works perfectly in the column of the row when I have manually dragged down the formula to BF3000, but I’d rather have the value of the formula displayed in the cell hard coded, than having the formula in the cells (same as if using copy & paste Values Only)

I use the code name of sheets (cnSample, cnTest) rather than the sheet name, just in case the user changes the name of the sheet (at least the code will still run without errors).

I’d really appreciate any assistance.
Cheers,
TheShyButterfly

UPDATE:
I'm working on coming together with a code that may be on the road to what I need.
Currently I have a working file, which is password protected, because I have numerous formulas that update when rows are completed.
The 'Report Number' works perfectly, if the cell of Column D has data in it. and if not, then the BF cell returns blank.
I just want to lighten the load on the workbook ... it is very slow in response for the user, that is why I am trying to integrate formulas via VBA.

Thank you all for your input and suggestions.

Comment: Post the code attempts you have made and where they are failing. SO is not a code-writing service. That said, `Worksheet_Change` event will help you hear. If you don't know where to begin, start there and break your logic into steps and then build code for each step. If you have *specific questions* based on that come back and ask!

Comment: Ok, thank you ... I'll give it a go.

Comment: Hard-coding is the way to go here and Worksheet_Change would be best to use as stated by Scott, but there are some issues which you need to address when you come to code your attempts as the formula is not future-proof as is. What happens if someone deletes or adds rows? currently your report numbers would become invalid or duplicated and this needs to be dealt with at the time of assigning a report number as they should be unique and unaltered upon worksheet changes.